# Design time access to Custom Attributes

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, design-time, design-time-data

Is there a way to access custom attributes (TCustomAttribute) ad design time. I have a custom form that has a custom module (from ICustomModule) registered. I would like to be able to access any custom attributes that have been defined for the form at design time.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **No**.

TCustomAttribute is directely derived from **TObject**.

Only registred **TComponent** descendents are avalaible in the **Tool Palette** of the IDE.

The IDE doesn't have a dedicated **View** to dispay all TCustomAttribute descendent referenced in all unit defined in the interface uses clause (Nevertheless you may extend the IDE, otherwise write an expert and install it).

Likewise, **Object Inspector** displays only **properties** and **events** of the form but *not* **annotations**.